# MOBX- React only inject single store from rootStore

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I want to implement a reactive design pattern to my react components. Therefore I use mobX but my core setup does not quite work as expected.
My setup is to have a rootstore and instatiate all sub-store in it. **At the end I want to inject only needed sub-stores within my react components.**

### UiStore

```
export default class UIStore {
      @observable language = {};

      constructor() {
        autorun(() => {console.log(this.language)})
      }


      @action
      async getLanguage() {
            const response = await new Promise((resolve) =>
              setTimeout(() => resolve({ language: 'en_GB' }), 1500)
            );

            runInAction(() => this.language = response);

      }
}
```

### Rootstore

```
// Inject all stores in this root store
class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.uiStore = new UIStore(this);
  }
}

const rootStore = new RootStore();
export default rootStore;
```

### index.js

```
const Root = () => (
  <MobXProvider rootStore={rootStore}>
    <App webSocketClient={GlobalWSC}/>
  </MobXProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

### App.jsx

```
    @inject(stores => ({
      uiStore: stores.uiStore // <== this does not work only: stores.rootStore.uiStore
    })
    )
    @observer
    class App extends React.Component {
      ...
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.uiStore.getLanguage(); //throws error cannot find function getLanguage()
  }
}
```

}

As you can see from the comment in App.jsx injecting the sub-store only works with `stores.rootStore.uiStore`, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you've defined it like that in your `MobXProvider`

In order to have desired behaviour define it like this

```
const Root = () => (
  <MobXProvider uiStore={uiStore}>
    <App webSocketClient={GlobalWSC}/>
  </MobXProvider>
);
```

Of course this is not good aproach since you'll have more stores within your root store so you'll have to somehow destruct your root store inner stores as `MobXProvider` props. Though I'm not sure why is that causing you problems (I've been using your syntax on multiple projects).

One of ways you could do this

```
class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.stores = {
        uiStore: new UIStore(this)
    }
  }
}

const Root = () => (
  <MobXProvider {...rootStore.stores}>
    <App webSocketClient={GlobalWSC}/>
  </MobXProvider>
);
```